# Convert HTML to DOCX on linux

Tags: html, docx

Is there a way to convert HTML to DOCX file on linux. I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382366/converting-html-to-odt-doc-docx, but did not find the right way to handle CSS while converting to DOCX.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use Java, you can convert your HTML to XHTML, and then use docx4j to import it.  The import is CSS aware.